# If $\ $ $ X\ =\ \left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5}........\right\}$ will $ P(X)$ be countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Question:

If $\ $ $ X\ =\ \left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5}........\right\}$ will $ P(X)$ be countable?

My attempt:

I think $X$ is countable since you can list all the elements. But I am not sure if that implies $P(X)$ is countable.

Comment: Is $P(X)$ the power set of $X$?

Comment: Yes it is the power set

Comment: Note: $X\sim \Bbb N$.  What do you know about the countability of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$?  Can you reason why $\Bbb N\sim X$ implies $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)\sim \mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: When $S$ is an infinite set, $P(S)$ is never countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X$ is clearly countably infinite, so $P(X)$ has the same cardinality as $P(\mathbb N)$, which is uncountable by Cantor's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem.

Comment: How does $ | X| = |\mathbb{N}| $ imply $ |P(X)| = |P(\mathbb{N})|$?

Comment: The statement that $\lvert X\rvert = \lvert\mathbb N\rvert$ means that we can find a bijection between these sets. Use this bijection to make a bijection between their power sets.

Comment: So $ f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ bijection implies $ f: P(\mathbb{N}) \to P(X)$ is a bijection, which is not true by Cantor's theorem?

Comment: Almost, you need to make a different map using $f$, say $g:P(\mathbb N)\to P(X)$. Let's take an arbitrary subset $S\in P(\mathbb N)$. Then, we can map it to an element of $P(X)$ via $g: S\mapsto\{f(s) : s\in S\}\subseteq X$. It's straightforward to see that this is a bijection, using the fact that $f$ is itself a bijection.